# kafka consumer code is not running completely

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i am trying a simple kafka producer consumer client api ,my producer class works fine as i can see the message in consumer from console but when i am running the consumer code nothing is getting displayed,i am not getting what is the problem or where i am doing mistake

this is producer code is -

```
package com.app.test;
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class SimpleProducer {
    private static Producer<Integer, String> producer;
    private final Properties props = new Properties();public    SimpleProducer()
    {
      props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
      props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
      props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
      producer = new Producer<Integer, String>(new ProducerConfig(props));
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleProducer sp = new SimpleProducer();
    String topic = "test4";
    String messageStr = "hello";
    KeyedMessage<Integer, String> data = new KeyedMessage<Integer, String>(topic, messageStr);
    System.out.println("producer : "+producer);
    producer.send(data);
    producer.close();
  }
}
```

consumer class is -

```
package com.app.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

public class SimpleHLConsumer {

  private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
  private final String topic;

  public SimpleHLConsumer(String zookeeper, String groupId, String topic) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);
    props.put("group.id", groupId);
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
    props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "250");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

    consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
    new ConsumerConfig(props));
    this.topic = topic;
  }



  public void testConsumer() {


    Map<String, Integer> topicCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Define single thread for topic
    topicCount.put(topic, new Integer(1));      

    System.out.println("check1");

    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);

    System.out.println("check2");
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerStreams.get(topic);

   for (KafkaStream stream : streams) {
        System.out.println("test----");
        System.out.println("test----"+stream.toString());
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIte = stream.iterator();
        while (consumerIte.hasNext()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Message from Single Topic: " + new String(consumerIte.next().message(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (consumer != null)
      consumer.shutdown();
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String topic = "test4";
SimpleHLConsumer simpleHLConsumer = new SimpleHLConsumer("localhost:2181", "testgroup", topic);
    simpleHLConsumer.testConsumer();
  }
}
```

for checking i have applied 2 checks by using sysout in testConsumer() method ,so while running only check1 is displayed i.e the code is not reaching check2 ,i think there is some problem with `consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);` , so what is the reason and how can i solve it ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73851/discussion-on-question-by-nsu-kafka-consumer-code-is-not-running-completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue in code.

Just build jar including **kafka-version**(version of kafka you are using) in your jar  and run it and try sending message from producer console.

Hope this could help you.